# C#: SQLiteDataAdapter INSERT is Slow

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, ado.net

I have a JSON File with ~25-30K items that I want to save in a sqlite database.
However the amount of time taken for SQLiteDataAdapter class to update the database with a DataTable object that has all the items is about 35mins for 15K items.
The performance of updates performed is limited by the UpdateBatchSize which is 1 in my case and when I try to change it I am getting an exception that says "Specified method is not supported".

Here is the Update method:

```
        public async Task<bool> SaveTable()
    {
        SQLiteDataAdapter data_adapter = null;
        try
        {

            data_adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql_cmd);
            data_adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 10;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Thrown: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            SQLiteCommandBuilder cmd_bldr = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(data_adapter);
            data_adapter.InsertCommand = cmd_bldr.GetInsertCommand();
            Console.WriteLine(data_adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText);
            data_adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
            data_adapter.UpdateCommand = data_adapter.InsertCommand;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Thrown: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            var size = data_adapter.UpdateBatchSize;
            Console.WriteLine("Updating Table. Batch Size: " + size);
            var rows_updated = data_adapter.Update(data_table);
            Console.WriteLine("Rows Updated: " + rows_updated.ToString());
            data_adapter.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Thrown: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Is there a way I can change UpdateBatchSize or increase the number of updates per second?

Comment: UpdateBatchSize when set to 1 [disables the functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize(v=vs.110).aspx). In the [source code of the SQLite DataAdapter](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/161266487edf0cd1) there is no override for this property. So, if it throws when you try to change it, then the functionality is not supported and the operations are executed row by row hence the slow performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your approach to use an SQLiteDataAdapter is wrong. The [UpdateBatchSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize(v=vs.110).aspx) property is not implemented by the SQLite connector and thus cannot be changed. The default value 1 means that the update batch functionality is disabled. So, the adapter, when requested to update, is forced to run a slow one row by one row process.

The best approach is manually execute each single insert command but **enclosing them in a transaction**

```
// Getting the command text from the SQLiteCommandBuilder, but at this
// point you could simply write it as text directly in the constructor
SQLiteCommandBuilder cmd_bldr = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(data_adapter);
using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmd_bldr.GetInsertCommand(), conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Create the parameters collection, setting the type for each 
    // parameter but without setting an explicit value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", DbType.Int);
    // create other parameters for each field to insert ....

    using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // Inform the command about the open transaction
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;

        // Loop over your table rows....
        foreach(DataRow row in data_table.Rows)
        {
            // get the parameters value from the row's field
            cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = row[fieldIndex];
            .... repeat for other parameters ...

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol, it completed updating the database instantly, thanks for the help!